# Chart color Repainting Candlestick Color C#

Tags: c#, plot, charts, colors

Hello I'm plotting a candle stick chart by setting the following property

```
chart1.Series[0].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Red,PriceUpColor=Green";
```

Everything works fine, charts plots as expected with the right colors.

Then I'm trying to to color some specific candles of my choosing with the following code.

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[i].Color = Color.Black;
```

Unfortunately the candle specified at point "i" will not repaint with the black color.

What I've tried to do is to comment out the above CustomProperty and the candlestick chart then plots with default colors(blue and light blue) and will color my specific candles with the black color.

My question is, how can I color specific candles at index "i" with my desired color if the above custom property is set to `chart1.Series[0].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Red,PriceUpColor=Green";`.

Is there any way to override this for a specific candle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to do a Refresh() on the chart. Usuually not needed, but when custom properties are involved it may hlelp..

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: Unfortunately iti did not But i got a little workaround using this piece of code in case the candle is either bullish or bearish.   // chart1.Series[0].Points[alerts[i] + 9]["PriceDownColor"] = "Black";
                        // chart1.Series[0].Points[alerts[i + 1] + 9]["PriceUpColor"] = "Black";